# Picking random urls from an XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

need a bit of help. I have an XML with a list of cities and the url's to images. The XML can have any number of cities on it however i want to have a section on the XSLT page were i just show a few images (lets say 4 out of the x amount of cities in the XML). Id like to be able to do this dynamically by picking any city at random that has the attribute url attached to it(so 4 different images of cities every time the page is loaded). Here's an example of my XML.

```
<Cities>
    <City Name="London" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Aberdeen" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Birmingham" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Bristol" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Cardiff" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Edinburgh" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Glasgow" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Liverpool" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Manchester" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Newcastle" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Paris" url="LinkToImage" />
    <City Name="Marseille" url="LinkToImage" />
...
```

would it help if I added another attribute i.e number="x". If possible id link to avoid this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Im not to sure if i can do this in XSLT or would I have to write a JavaScript function.... either way im not sure how to tackle it. Im not sure how to make it random once i loop through Cities.

Comment: There isn't any random functions in XSLT. Sure you could write (or use an existing) one, but you're far better off either picking a random element from the result, or passing in a random number as a parameter to the stylesheet to use.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Please, try to be more precise: There isn't any *standard* XSLT or XPath function for generating random numbers. FXSL provided such functions/templates almost 10 years ago.

Comment: @Dimitre: That's why I said *in* XSLT, instead of *for* XSLT. Given that I also mentioned the possibility of using an existing function, it should have been fairly clear I was referring to standard XSLT.

Comment: @Flynn1179: It *wasn't* clear and do remember that the prevailing majority of SO readers aren't expected (and indeed aren't) native English speakers.

Comment: @Dimitre: Feel free to poll the prevailing majority of SO readers if you wish, but I'm confident it would be clear to most. At least try to realise that 'not clear to you' != 'not clear to anyone'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example to do it from a string. To get that string (from a file for example) you can use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started)'s `responseXML` property.

```
var doc = 
    '<Cities>' +
    '<City Name="London" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Aberdeen" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Birmingham" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Bristol" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Cardiff" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Edinburgh" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Glasgow" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Liverpool" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Manchester" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Newcastle" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Paris" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '<City Name="Marseille" url="LinkToImage" />' +
    '</Cities>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(doc, "text/xml"); //Convert the text to XML object

var cities = xml.getElementsByTagName("Cities")[0].childNodes; //Get all child of Cities
var randomCity = Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length); //Pick one at random
var city = cities[randomCity]; //Get it using it's index
alert(city.getAttribute("Name")); //Show it's name
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/f8Ugn/

Comment: If that solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer as the solution to your question by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

See whether http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/Random/Casting%20the%20Dice%20with%20FXSL-htm.htm helps.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to create a sequence of pseudo-random numbers in pure XSLT (1.0 or 2.0).**

See my work "*Casting the Dice with FXSL: Random Number Generation Functions in XSLT*" **[here](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/Random/Casting%20the%20Dice%20with%20FXSL-htm.htm)**.

Of course, if you not to generate the same sequence of numbers on every transformation, you need to pass as parameter to the transformation something that is different every time -- this could be, for example, the current time in minutes.